# How to bypass SSL certificate error in Windows CE

Tags: c#, .net, windows-ce

I want to bypass the SSL certificate error of web service in Windows CE.

There are many solutions for .net Windows applications such as;

[Bypass invalid SSL certificate errors when calling web services in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109186/bypass-invalid-ssl-certificate-errors-when-calling-web-services-in-net)

But in windows ce I can not import ServicePointManager library.

So is there another way to do this in Windows CE ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can in fact use the ServicePointManager in the CF as well.
First, create a policy that accepts everything, as so:

```
public class TrustAllCertificatePolicy : ICertificatePolicy
{
    public TrustAllCertificatePolicy()
    {
    }

    public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint sp,
        X509Certificate cert, WebRequest req, int problem)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

To use this class, you should run the following code once per application session (each time the application is started; the TrustAllCertificatePolicy instance will be used each time an SSL connection is made), and before you make any Web requests (preferably on application startup).

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new TrustAllCertificatePolicy();
```

This solution is equivalent to answering yes to any security messages that would normally appear in a browser.

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738067.aspx)

Comment: This makes the use of https irrelevant. Dont do it. This is like answering Yes to "Do you want to get hacked" question. http://labs.rebex.net/HTTPS

Comment: Yep, I agree. Hence my last remark in the post. Sometimes, though, you aren't in control of the service you're trying to consume (to give it a valid certificate), and yet you must consume it :) Of course, you can always fine-tune this to only accept certain invalid certificates, I leave that up to the OP

Comment: It doesn't make HTTPS irrelevant at all. It leaves you open to man in the middle attacks when opening the connection, but it's still far better than sending everything in the clear.

Additionally, Windows CE no longer seems to validate many certificates correctly, leaving no other option.