# what is ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I'm using a web service in my website. the provider provide me a sample code, in the code there is a line like this:

```
// For Ignore SSL Error
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
```

The web service link users to its own page and then return to my website. it uses **https**.

What is this code application? Is it for ignoring **certification error** in users' web explorers?

I think the certification with the web server's site may not be valid certification, or it's just a local certification. Am I right?

Thanks.

Comment: It is for bypassing invalid SSL certificate.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109186/bypass-invalid-ssl-certificate-errors-when-calling-web-services-in-net

Answer (score 5):

It is common mistake to think that it is used only to bypass invalid SSL certificates. However, many uses this callback only to ignore invalid certificates.

This callback provides an ability to attach additional checks for SSL certificate and access information cannot be accessed otherwise. For example, only within this callback you can get specific certificate errors which cannot be handled externally: name match/mismatch (they are stored in the `sslPolicyErrors` parameter. In addition, `chain` parameter contains exact certificate chain sent by the server. This object can be used to construct the certificate chain when system store has missing intermediate CA certificates.

For example, when you purchase certificates from Thawte (or other providers), their certificate do not have 'Certification Authority Issuer' access method and intermediate certificates are not installed in the system store. In this case, you will be unable to build the chain for that certificate. However, web browsers will not complain because missing (on client) certificates are shipped along the SSL handshake from web server. And this callback is the only way to access them.

And I wouldn't bypass SSL errors in a production environments, because it will open security holes.