# Can not add web service reference

Tags: c#, web-services

I've been given a Url like:

```
https://xxxx.gr/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx?WSDL
```

to create a consumer.

For testing reasons I've started a new desktop application in C# and when I tried to add the service reference I get the following error:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Then I tried to hit that Url direct from each browser (IE, FireFox, Chrome).  They all report that it is insecure connection.

For example, in FireFox I get this info:

```
https:xxxx/xxx/xxx?WSDL

Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.

HTTP Strict Transport Security: false
HTTP Public Key Pinning: false

Certificate chain:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I search the web and also SO but I couldn't figure it out.

Is there something I could do or the problem is from service side?

PS I'm completely ignorant about certificates etc.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to install https certificate from your service provider.

Answer (score 2):

put the certificate into the authors trusted and retry.

Comment: If it's not trouble to you, can you be more specific? Thanks anyway.

Comment: open internet explorer > tools>internet option> tab content 
click on certificate button 
choose tab "Trusterd Publishers" 
click on import button and fallow the procedures...

Comment: Thank you for your time but I don't have a certificate file to import. After searching I understood that maybe the server administrator (of the service) did not match correct the certificate or it is self-signed (like for intranet use). Either it's possible because it is a test service. For me I think the only thing I can do is to load the service at run time (not add it as service reference) and create all the proxy classes manually. I think, not sure enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the certificate error if you just want to be able to create your client proxy classes, as per this answer: [Bypass invalid SSL certificate errors when calling web services in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/427820/2039359)

```
...
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = MyCertHandler;
...

static bool MyCertHandler(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
{
   // Ignore errors
   return true;
}
```

Comment: The question is for when adding a web reference in Visual Studio, not calling the actual webservice.